# Red wine service

Tags: wine, serving, red-wine

I want organize a meeting around Italian wine but I have multiple question in my brain.

I read a lot of page in this big web for prepare wine.

My wine is not into a fridge. I know my red wine may be openned 1h before the degustation but I do not know if I need to kept the wine 1h hour in  the fridge before opening it. Because I saw after 1h the wine temperature was between 19°C or 20°C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a safe bet, dry still red wines should be served between 18-20°C
Of course exceptions apply...

Opening time prior to service depends on the vintage, older wines (4+ years) need to breathe longer than young wines (0-3 years).

Knowing what kind of wine you have would help, denomination and vintage being the most useful information.

Comment: Thank you. I have a Toscani wine 2008 (Syrah, petit-verdot) and Barolo 2002. Your instruction for older wine is nice for me. I have found a response with my vendor for opening wine. Thx

Answer (score 2):

An excellent practice is also read the wine back label. In some cases there is information about the "serving temprature" and also this maybe can be found on the winnery webpage. Some wineries web site are in their local language as well as English.